# Chromecast v3| Android | how to use custom namespace?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am creating a sender app in Android and want to use custom name space like

```
urn:x-abced
```

how can I update sender app to use custom namespace for communication?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Cast.MessageReceivedCallback with the namespace you want to receive the messages from the receiver application.

To send the message from sender app with a your namespace you can use CastSession.sendMessage method.

But as the API says, your namespace must always have prefix - "**urn:x-cast:**"

reference : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastSession#sendMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)